# Can't insert items into table after google authentication in Azure mobile service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am testing the sample code from Azure Mobile Service site. It's a todo app for iOS. There is a button to create a table for this app in the Azure site. And the app works well.

But after I turned on authentication for google option in the site, I couldn't insert or fetch todos from Azure server. I signed in google through the app and MSClient:loginWithProvider was successful.

```
    [self.todoService.client loginWithProvider:@"google" controller:self animated:YES completion:^(MSUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error==nil) {
            // obviously successful
            NSLog(@"login success %@", user.userId);
        }

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```

But whenever I inserted new todo, I got this error.

```
2016-02-03 00:15:52.311 TryMobileApp[7432:1327892] Error Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1201 "The server did not return the expected item." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The server did not return the expected item., com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorRequestKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7c258d90> { URL: http://thehome.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem }, com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorResponseKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ae095e0> { URL: https://thehome.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 326;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Tue, 02 Feb 2016 16:15:51 GMT";
Etag = "W/\"186-ChUpLnifKBz6ME0BS21A5w\"";
Expires = 0;
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
"X-Powered-By" = "Express, ASP.NET";
```

} }}

If I turned off the authentication option in the Azure site, it worked well again.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Based on the error message, the server returned a 200 (successful) response. How are you calling the `insert` method on the `MSTable` object? And do you have any scripts / custom logic on the server side?

Comment: Error's gone. I have no idea what happened. I remove an app and create new one, then it works!